# Bookmarklet to open an empty tab/window with some javascript in it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I know there are a lot of discussions about opening http pages in new windows and tabs,

but that's not what i'm looking for.

How do I open an **empty** new tab and run some arbitrary js in it?

That is when someone clicks my bookmarklet, a new tab should appear and code such as "document.write(foo)" should run in it with foo coming from the js on the tab where bookmarklet was clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

This bookmarklet is the translation of your question:

```
javascript:void(function(foo){
    var d=window.open("");
    d.document.open();
    d.document.write(foo);
    d.document.close();
})("Foo")
```